Question on dimensions of CFT operators like $\exp({\cal O})$
I want to find the scaling dimension of the operator $e^{-iφ}$ in my system:
$$
H=H_{\text{Dot}}+H_{\text{Leads}}+H_{\text{tunneling}}+H_{\text{Env}}
$$
Where:
$$
H_{\text{Env}} = {Q^2 \over 2C}+ \sum_{n}\left[\frac{q_n^2}{2C_n }+ \left({\hbar\over e}\right)^2 \left({1 \over 2L_n}\right) (\phi-\phi_n)^2\right] 
$$
$$
H_{\text{tunneling}} = V_S \sum_k\left(c_{kS}^{\dagger} e^{-i\phi/2} d +h.c.\right)
$$
How can I find an $\exp(\cdot)$ of an operator scaling dimension?
